# Grails Dynamic links in static resources

Tags: grails, web

To link a controller / action, g:createLink is useful. But if the resource is static like javascript how to create dynamic link? As these pages not parsed in tomcat container as gsp pages, is there any solution instead of specifying statically.

Comment: Are you looking to have dynamic content inside unparsed files such as CSS and Javascript files? (e.g. using createLink inside a .js file)

Answer (score 1):

Make the file extension to "filenName.fileType.gsp". For example, if you want to use resource tag inside "main.css" file, you should rename it to "main.css.gsp".

Note : You might loose IDE auto-complete after this..

Answer (score 0):

I think the [resource tag](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/resource.html) is what you are looking for:

```
// generates "/shop/css/main.css"
<g:resource dir="css" file="main.css" />

// generates "http://portal.mygreatsite.com/css/main.css" 
<g:resource dir="css" file="main.css" absolute="true" />

// generates "http://admin.mygreatsite.com/css/main.css" 
<g:resource dir="css" file="main.css" base="http://admin.mygreatsite.com"/>
```

(copied from the documentation page)